# How to find files which were last modified 1 year ago

Tags: c#, last-modified, file-search

I am writing some code for a program that archives files. So I need to find files which were last modified one year ago.

```
string[] as_Datien = Directory.GetFiles(s_Pfad, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int i_Stelle = 0; i_Stelle < as_Datien.GetLength(0); i_Stelle++)
{
}
```

I want to check if a file was last modified 1 year ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *Linq* and [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) to get file's last modification date:

```
  DateTime threshold = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

  // files which was modified earlier than 1 year ago
  string[] as_Datien = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(s_Pfad, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime < threshold)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `File.GetLastWriteTime()` method.
It returns the date and time of the last edition of files and/or folders.

Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_) out.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned use `File.GetLastWriteTime()` and check that date against today's date one year ago using `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)`